# Recursively construct JSON till nth level for tree view by using RXJS Operators

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to construct the n-level treeview with rxjs. I achieved the same with plain javascript. Find the js code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/CEryMRDeCkNOfPIozQJx?p=preview)

```js
var x = [{"id":1,"name":"Admin","parentDepartmentId":null},{"id":2,"name":"Development","parentDepartmentId":1},{"id":3,"name":"Research and Development","parentDepartmentId":1},{"id":4,"name":"FE","parentDepartmentId":2},{"id":5,"name":"BE","parentDepartmentId":2},{"id":6,"name":"Testing","parentDepartmentId":1},{"id":7,"name":"Unit Test","parentDepartmentId":6},{"id":8,"name":"Integration Test","parentDepartmentId":6},{"id":9,"name":"HR","parentDepartmentId":null}];

function getRecords(parents) {
    parents.forEach((parent) => {
      var result = getChildData(parent);
      parent.items = result;
      if (result.length > 0) {
        getRecords(result);
      }
    })
  return parents;
}
  
function getChildData(parent) {
    return x.filter(record => record.parentDepartmentId == parent.id)
}

function getParents(x){
    return  x.filter(record => record.parentDepartmentId == null);
}

var parents = getParents(x)
var result = getRecords(parents);
console.log(result);
```

Can someone show some lights on this.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I could generate from an https://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/.   You may want to clean it up a bit though, like making Data and Data1 use a same class making isNode optional. Converter can come in handy when you have to do a lot of this.

```
    Also you may want to make these as class instead of interface if what you want is class.

   export interface Weather {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  parentDepartmentId?: null;
  items?: (ItemsEntity | null)[] | null;
}
export interface ItemsEntity {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  parentDepartmentId: number;
  items?: (ItemsEntity1 | null)[] | null;
}
export interface ItemsEntity1 {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  parentDepartmentId: number;
  items?: (null)[] | null;
}
```